# why the exception does not display a message in pl sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The user gives the name of the department, and if the given department does not exist, an exception should be displayed 'Given department is not exists', but now display only PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. Someone could show me where is error ?

```
DECLARE 
    v_result varchar2(30) := '&given_department';
    CURSOR cur IS 
    SELECT department_name FROM employees 
    JOIN departments using(department_id) 
    WHERE department_name = v_result  for update of commission_pct;
BEGIN
    for bonus in cur
    loop
        update employees set commission_pct = commission_pct + 0.05 
        where current of cur;
    end loop;
exception
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Given department is not exists');
END;
```

Comment: If it says "procedure successfully completed", why do you think there should be an error? When an error is thrown, the procedure is not completed "successfully", that should be pretty obvious even to the non-English speaker.

Comment: do you have "set serveroutput on" ?

Answer (score 0):

Code you wrote can't raise `NO_DATA_FOUND`. `SELECT` does, but not when it is within cursor declaration. If such a department isn't found, Oracle *silently* exits the loop and does nothing. Exception is never executed.

Therefore, you'll have to check whether there's anything returned by a cursor. As you have to actually *open* and *fetch* to see that, you can either do exactly that, or use a local variable which will be incremented for every loop round. Then, after the loop, check its value and display appropriate message.

Something like this:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_result  VARCHAR2 (30) := '&given_department';
  3
  4     CURSOR cur IS
  5            SELECT department_name
  6              FROM employees JOIN departments USING (department_id)
  7             WHERE department_name = v_result
  8        FOR UPDATE OF commission_pct;
  9
 10     l_cnt     NUMBER := 0;
 11  BEGIN
 12     FOR bonus IN cur
 13     LOOP
 14        UPDATE employees
 15           SET commission_pct = commission_pct + 0.05
 16         WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
 17
 18        l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     IF l_cnt = 0
 22     THEN
 23        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Given department does not exist');
 24     ELSE
 25        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Updated ' || l_cnt || ' row(s)');
 26     END IF;
 27  END;
 28  /
Enter value for given_department: TEST
Given department does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for given_department: ACCOUNTING
Updated 3 row(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your requirement is using a cursor and loop over each this could done with a single update statement. The need to print a message makes it necessary to first retrieve the department id - making the no-data-found exception appropriate - but then still just a single update. The point is when working with SQL do not think in terms of loops, but the entire set at once.

```
declare 
    v_dept departments.department_id%type;
begin
    select department_id
      into v_dept
      from departments 
     where department_name = '&given_department'; 
     
    update employees 
       set commission_pct = commission_pct + 0.05 
     where department = v_dept; 
         
exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('Given department is not exists');
    when too_many_rows then
        dbms_output.put_line('There are multiple given dapartments');        
end;
```